# SQLITE: select in query, subquery data with WHERE IN

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following query:

```
SELECT en_lect, en_main, en_opref, en_id, en_meros, en_family, en_header 
FROM entries 
WHERE en_id IN ( 
      SELECT en_family 
      FROM entriesSmallSplit 
      WHERE (en_tonismenosplit = ?) AND (en_ref = 0) AND (en_se = 0) 
) 
ORDER BY en_meros DESC, en_id DESC;
```

The `entriesSmallSplit` table in the subquery has a column called `FirstLetter`. I want to be able to return the data that `FirstLetter` contains in the results of the first query `SELECT en_lect, en_main, en_opref, en_id, en_meros, en_family, en_header`. The `entriesSmallSplit` table structure:

```
en_tonismenosplit, en_family, FirstLetter, en_ref, en_se
---------------------------------------
aaa, 123, g, 0, 0
bbb, 123, f, 0, 0
ccc, 321, f, 0, 0
```

`entries` table structure

```
en_id, en_lect, en_main, en_opref, en_meros, en_family, en_header
---------------------------------------
123, ddd, 1, 0, 5, 123, 44
473, eee, 2, 0, 6, 473, 55
```

if the user queries `aaa` I want the result to be:

`ddd, 1, 0, 123, 5, 123, 44, g` (where **g** is in the `entriesSmallSplit` table)

is this possible, how can I do this in an efficient way?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT en_lect, en_main, en_opref, en_id, en_meros, e.en_family, en_header, FirstLetter 
FROM entries AS e
JOIN entriesSmallSplit AS ess ON en_id = ess.en_family
WHERE en_tonismenosplit = ? AND en_ref = 0 AND en_se = 0 
ORDER BY en_meros DESC, en_id DESC;
```

---

For efficiency, you'll want indexes on `entries(en_id)` and on `entriesSmallSplit(en_tonimenosplit, en_ref, en_se, en_family)`. These will eliminate the need for full table scans; only relevant rows of both tables will be looked at and those that cannot possibly be returned will be skipped completely.

Comment: Thank you, your and scaisEdge answers are both the same, I only clicked his as the accepted, because it's faster (85ms instead of 120ms on my PC) due to the inner clause instead of a simple JOIN.

Comment: @MirrorMirror Once you fix the other one to include the `FirstLetter` column you wanted, they actually compile to the exact same bytecode. (`INNER JOIN` and `JOIN` are the same thing). It's mostly a matter of style and personal preference if you put filters in a `WHERE` or `ON`; I prefer the former for things that don't explicitly link rows in the two tables.

Comment: yes, I have already fixed it. For some reason in sqlite expert personal it's faster, I don't know why. I will probably have to see the schema to see why. Yours is actually more readable as it has the WHERE

Answer (score 2):

Instead of an IN clause you could use an  inner join

```
SELECT e.en_lect, e.en_main, e.en_opref, e.en_id, e.en_meros, e.en_family, e.en_header 
FROM entries e
INNER JOIN entriesSmallSplit  s ON s.en_family = e.en_id 
  AND s.en_tonismenosplit = ?
    AND s.en_ref = 0
      AND s.en_se = 0
```

and INNER JOIN is normally more efficent respect  to IN clause  ..  because a IN clause is equivalent to several . the INNER JOIN is a single query only

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN` to implement this.

```
SELECT e.en_lect, e.en_main, e.en_opref, e.en_id, e.en_meros, e.en_family, e.en_header, ess.FirstLetter
FROM entries AS e
INNER JOIN entriesSmallSplit AS ess
ON e.en_family=ess.en_family
WHERE ess.en_tonismenosplit="aaa"
```